# Acceptable way to expose an object manager's objects?

Tags: c++, oop, boost, smart-pointers

Scenario is, I'm building a game with a TextureManager class that is responsible for loading and managing textures. Game objects implementing IVisibleGameObject will need a pointer/reference to a texture from the TextureManager.

Texture manager is implemented with a `std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Texture> >` to hold its objects internally.

I'm not certain how I should actually expose the textures, and thought of a few possibilities, each with their own downsides:

1) `const Texture& GetTex(std::string textureKey)`

I feel would be ideal, but I'd like to indicate that a texture was not found in the map by returning NULL. (Second guessing myself...IS this appropriate?)

2) `shared_ptr<const Texture> GetTex(std::string textureKey)`

Here I could return a null shared_ptr, but I'm uncomfortable with the implication it's a shared object now. The TextureManager is the object's owner, it's the manager after all. However, considering the fact an IVisibleGameObject holds a reference/pointer to the returned Texture and depends on its existence to function correctly, isn't it also an owner of the object, and maybe shared ownership is appropriate?

3) `const Texture* GetTex(stD::string textureKey)`

Obviously, this is the wrong answer.

Would love for someone to clear this up for me, perhaps there is something I haven't considered.

Comment: Does 2 work? I don't think you can directly convert a `shared_ptr<Texture>` to a `shared_ptr<const Texture>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with the standard library idiom and simply expose `find` and `end`. Then you can be perfectly efficient:

```
auto it = my_objects.find("foo");

if (it == my_objects.end())
{
    // handle "not found"
}
else
{
    it->second->do_magic();
}
```

The standard library already has a perfectly serviceable, generic idiom for handling collections and signaling presence or absence of elements, as well as combining insert-new-or-return-existing semantics. Why reinvent the wheel...

Comment: If I expose the object through the TextureManager interface, aren't I left with the same problem since `it->second` is still just the shared_ptr? Why not just expose the shared_ptr in this case?

Comment: @Drism: You could use a `boost::transform_iterator` that dereferences into a `Texture&`. Then you could store `std::unique_ptr<Texture>`s in the map, too. Or perhaps store the texture in the map directly?

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is have the TextureManager hold the single shared pointer to each texture and make the GameObjects hold weak pointers. That way you can be sure you freed everything properly on exit (guaranteed no cycles).

Comment: I've considered this as well, but something has always confused me about weak_ptrs. Why use a weak_ptr when it will ultimately be turned into a strong pointer anyways? Is it simply because the object's reference count isn't incremented until absolutely necessary? And when should the newly made strong pointer be reset?

Comment: Because weak pointers are the only way to break cycles. You lock the pointer only while you're doing stuff with it, but it is stored as a weak pointer so it doesn't prevent destruction.